# Why is Python XLSWRITER Cell formula does not work programmatically?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have these simple codes that get the SUM of A1, A2 and A3.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0, 0, 5, None)
worksheet.write(1, 0, 3, None)
worksheet.write(2, 0, 9, None)
worksheet.write(3, 0, '=SUM(A1:A3)', None)

workbook.close()
```

Theoretically it should work. But it's not. (See image below)

[image]

But if I manually change one of the 3 numbers then it will work.

[image]

Manually changing its numbers are no good bc the excel is a generated file via python program, I cannot just say to the client to manually change a 1 number of their choice and change it back when the sum formula works.

Send help senior Programmers.

Comment: Untested, but try `worksheet.write(3, 0, '=SUM(A1:A3)', None, 13)`. This should set the "value" parameter of the underlying "write_formula" method.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html)

> **XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead
> stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag
> in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be
> recalculated when the file is opened.**
>
> **This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in
> general it works fine with spreadsheet applications.** However,
> applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas will
> only display the 0 results. Examples of such applications are Excel
> Viewer, PDF Converters, and some mobile device applications.
>
> If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of
> the formula using the optional `value` parameter for `write_formula()`

Check the link for more info and examples.

Answer (score 1):

From the XlsxWriter [FAQ](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-why-do-my-formulas-show-a-zero-result-in-some-non-excel-applications):

> **Q. Why do my formulas show a zero result in some, non-Excel applications?**
>
> Due to a wide range of possible formulas and the interdependencies between them XlsxWriter doesn’t, and realistically cannot, calculate the result of a formula when it is written to an XLSX file. Instead, it stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened.
>
> This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However, applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas, such as Excel Viewer, or several mobile applications, will only display the 0 results.
>
> If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of the formula using the optional value parameter in `write_formula()`:
>
> ```
> worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=2+2', None, 4)
> ```
>
> Note: LibreOffice doesn’t recalculate Excel formulas that reference other cells by default, in which case you will get the default XlsxWriter value of 0. You can work around this by setting the “LibreOffice Preferences -> LibreOffice Calc -> Formula -> Recalculation on File Load” option to “Always recalculate” (see the LibreOffice documentation). Or, you can set a blank result in the formula, which will also force recalculation:
>
> ```
> worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=Sheet1!$A$1', None, '')
> ```

From your screenshot it looks like you are using LibreOffice or OpenOffice so you can try the suggested workaround of adding a blank result:

```
worksheet.write(3, 0, '=SUM(A1:A3)', None, '')
```

Comment: thank you good sir, I tried this and it works.
worksheet.write(3, 0, '=SUM(A1:A3)', None, '')
I tot only 4 parameters is allowed so I removed None and replaced it by '' --
I mean, I think of it before but never tried it bc of thinking 4 parameters is the limit. wahaha thanks sir